# How to get source of VC++ error when debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, runtime-error, c++17

Whenever I'm debugging in Visual C++ and I get a runtime error, it just brings me to some cryptic file (usually x${something}). How can I actually access/see the source of this error? (e.g. which line of code caused it)

Comment: Change the "Stack Frame: " combo box on the top toolbar to your code.

Comment: @drescherjm Could you screenshot that option? Because I'm having trouble finding it. Thanks.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JAPEwgw.png